# How to fix the TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined

Tags: javascript

this is my part of the problem

```
const {Discord,Client, Attachment, MessageAttachment, DiscordAPIError} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'NzIzNDgxNjczNDA0MjUyMjU5.XuyQ0A.eDXJl2ZdBzQRcIZJrQRHR9qO6sE';

const PREFIX = '/'; 

const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.command.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log('this bot is online!')
    client.user.setActivity('Music in another wolrd',{type:'LISTENING'}).catch(console.error);

})
```

and my terminal show this

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot\index.js:3:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I already npm install but still don't work how should I do
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: Did you install the `discord.js` library? If not then you should open the directory where your script is located in the terminal. Run `npm init`,  and then run `npm install discord.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import it like `const Discord = require('discord.js');`

OR

As you are already destructuring it, you can use like `const client = new Client();`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'NzIzNDgxNjczNDA0MjUyMjU5.XuyQ0A.eDXJl2ZdBzQRcIZJrQRHR9qO6sE';
const PREFIX = '/'; 

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.command.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log('this bot is online!')
    client.user.setActivity('Music in another wolrd',{type:'LISTENING'}).catch(console.error);

})
```

Comment: thank you to answer but still have a problem

Comment: @Ihaveproblemwith.js, you mean, same issue? and which one you tried?

Comment: SyntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared

Comment: in const client = new Discord.Client();

Comment: This error you'll get only when you declare same const more than once. so are you declaring `const client` twice?

Comment: @Ihaveproblemwith.js, added updated code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js does not export a discord class therefore you cannot destructe it from Discord.js